# Some unexpected output if negative numbers inputted

Tags: character-encoding, integer

I am working on a CS project, and I am confused about some aspect of the code.

I tried to use '0' to remove the character value stored in the fDig and sDig to hold integers instead of character bytes, but somehow then when I made distance the negative of itself, the cerr read out some random number not intended again.

```cpp
    else{
                int fDig = commandString[i+1+extra]-'0';
                int sDig = commandString[i+2+extra]-'0';
                int distance = fDig;


                if (isdigit(commandString[i+2])){distance = (fDig*10 + sDig);}
                if (extra == 1){distance = -distance;}

                cerr << distance << endl;
}
```

For example if commandString at i+1+extra is 3, and commandString at i+2+extra is nothing, and that extra is 1. I get the value 18 as output for distance.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting `'0'` doesn't magically turn a char in a string into an integer.

By subtracting `'0'`, you are subtracting from the ASCII value to get the offset from ASCII 0:

```c
'0' - '0' = 0x30 - 0x30 = 0
'1' - '0' = 0x31 - 0x30 = 1
'2' - '0' = 0x32 - 0x30 = 2
'3' - '0' = 0x33 - 0x30 = 3
...
'9' - '1' = 0x39 - 0x30 = 9
```

However, if you have garbage data (which in user input, you should always assume you do), you get garbage results:

```c
'-'  - '0' = 0x2d - 0x30 = -3
' '  - '0' = 0x20 - 0x30 = -16
'\0' - '0' = 0x00 - 0x30 = -48 (string terminator)
'\n' - '0' = 0x0a - 0x30 = -38
```

The C/C++ standard library has many tools written to do this for us.

Don't bother with ASCII parsing unless you *ABSOLUTELY* know what you are doing.

For a single number, I suggest [`strtoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) for C strings and [`stoll`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) for `std::strings`, or for multiple numbers in one string, [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) and [`istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream).

These handle hexadecimal, negatives, octal, extra whitespace, and error handling if you use it properly, and are much, much, MUCH easier than manual parsing.